# yum leaves obsoletes dependencies behind

Tags: rpm, yum

My problem is that I have a package containing multiple RPMs, say rpmA, rpmB, rpmC.  rpmC depends on rpmA and the versions are locked together so rpmC(v1) depends on rpmA(v1).

But package v2 has obsoleted rpmC and contains rpmA(v2) and rpmB(v2).  The SPEC file for rpmA(v2) does indicate that rpmC(v1) is obsoleted but I can't get yum to let me upgrade to v2 - anyone know why?

What yum seems to be doing is attempting to upgrade rpmA and rpmB but then it throws an error because it has not removed rpmC(v1) and rpmC(v1) requires rpmA(v1), which has been removed and upgraded to rpmA(v2).

Sadly I didn't control the original v1 RPMs so I can't, for example, make rpmC(v1) depend on rpmA(>=v1) and I also can't find a way to make yum let me do the upgrade.

Suggestions for what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: We would have to see the headers of each RPM spec probably, or at least the exact error. You can try a "`Provides`" as well as "`Obsoletes`" and see if that helps.

Comment: OK, will try and get more detail later today but I have tried adding a 'provides' and it seems to make no difference.

Comment: The RPMs being built are a new version of Erlang and it has retired a number of RPMs.  What I've tried to do is have the 'top-level' Erlang RPM obsolete the RPMs that are no longer required.  So the SPEC file contains 'Required' entries for the RPMs that do still exist and then Provides and Obsoletes for those that no longer exist:

    ....
    Requires: erlang-asn1%{?_isa} = %{version}-%{release}`
    ...

    Provides: erlang-appmon%{?_isa}
    ...
    
    Obsoletes: erlang-appmon%{?_isa}       < %{version}-%{release}
    ...

Comment: Apologies for the formatting above - cannot get the code into a proper code block :-(.

Comment: Now you are talking about subpackages, which are kind of special. This might help: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Upgrade_paths_%E2%80%94_renaming_or_splitting_packages

Comment: Umm, is the idea that to remove a subpackage I need a two step process?  #1 is to ALSO install a 'compat' RPM that provides the (soon to be) obsoleted interfaces.  #2 is to delete the RPMs that natively provide the interfaces.  Then at some point in the future, #3 would be to remove the compat RPM, which was carefully generated so that it did not depend on ANYTHING and can therefore always be deleted?

Comment: I meant the section labelled "Many-to-one replacement" where it says to have the new main package `Obsolete` the previous subpackages. Don't `Require` or `Provide` them.

Comment: Thanks - the 'Many to one' was what I originally tried.  It seems to my that yum is not at all helpful with 'package+sub-packages' because there are a number of possibilities: 1/ It might be a straight forward 'update all', 2/ There may be one or more packages to obsolete in which case 'update --obsolete' is required, 3/ There may be one of more new sub-packages, and these need to be 'install'ed. Seems that 'yum shell' works but I have to figure out install/update for the packages and sub-packages - sigh.

Comment: I may be onto something.  It seems that the sub-packages provide BOTH 'feature' and 'feature(x86_64)' and my obsoletes directives were only obsoleting the 'feature(x86_64)'.  Adding TWO obsoletes, one for 'feature' and one for 'feature(x86_64)' looks like it might be working.  So I'm off complete the process and see if this is really true.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, the issue is that each RPM implicitly provides both 'feature' and 'feature(architecture)' e.g. 'ssl' and 'ssl(x86_64)'.  My obsoletes explicitly included the architecture so only obsoleted (e.g.) 'ssl(x86_64)' leaving 'ssl' behind to generate unresolved dependencies.

If you remove the architecture from the obsoletes directive, then *both* the 'feature' and 'feature(architecture)' are obsoleted and things all start to work.

So to recap:

1. Use obsoletes, having one of the remaining RPMs obsolete the RPMs that you will delete as part of the upgrade
2. Do NOT specify an architecture in the obsoletes directives so that all instances of the feature/RPM are deleted
3. At the same time, consider whether your require directives specify specific versions of dependencies or use >= which might allow an up-level dependency to work - that's biting me too!

The joy of inheriting RPM definitions :-).

Comment: Hmm. The whole arch thing with x86_64 vs i686 can be confusing sometimes.

Comment: I see - so the 'no achitecture' stuff is actually the i686 (which I think is the 32-bit implementation) ?